# Keyword search with negative keywords

Tags: go, keyword

I have a simple question about keywords searching in a Go.

I want to search a string using positive and negative keywords

```
func keyword(itemTitle string, keywords string) bool {
    splits := strings.Split(keywords, ",")
    for _, item := range splits {
        item = strings.TrimSpace(item)

        fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(itemTitle))
        fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(item))

        if strings.Contains(item,"-") {
            item = item[1:]
            if strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(itemTitle), strings.ToUpper(item)) {
                return false
            }
        }

        item = item[1:]
        fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(item))

        if strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(itemTitle), strings.ToUpper(item)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

heres my searcher method

```
func TestKeyword(t *testing.T) {
    test1 := "Pokemon Nintendo Switch Cool Thing"
    keywordTest1 := "+pokemon,-nintendo"

    if keyword(test1, keywordTest1) {
        fmt.Println("matched")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("test")
    }

    test2 := "Pokemon Cards Cool"

    if keyword(test2, keywordTest1) {
        fmt.Println("matched")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("test")
    }
}
```

my test cases
i understand why its not working because +amd is the first in the slice and its ofc going to return true and not test any of the other like -radeon but im just kinda stumped on what todo.

Output given

```
matched
matched
```

Expected Output

```
test
matched
```

Comment: What is the actual problem, can you include the actual and expected output

Comment: @AshishMJ done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your search function but kept the signature

```
func keyword(itemTitle string, keywords string) bool {
    a := strings.ToUpper(itemTitle)
    b := strings.ToUpper(keywords)
    keys := strings.Split(strings.Replace(b, "-", " ", -1), ",")
    for _, key := range keys {
        key = strings.TrimSpace(key)
        if strings.Contains(a, key) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And updated your test function with a passing test and a failed one to see how it works.

```
func TestKeyword(t *testing.T) {
    test1 := "Pokemon Nintendo Switch Cool Thing"
    keywordTest1 := "+pokemon,-nintendo"

    if keyword(test1, keywordTest1) {
        t.Log("matched")
    } else {
        t.Fail()
    }

    test2 := "Pokemon Cards Cool"

    if keyword(test2, keywordTest1) {
        t.Log("matched")
    } else {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Regarding the second test failing with a keyword with + on it, you could pass that through a regex to get only alphanumeric characters, if required.

Comment: Hmm i see that i doesn't work for the second case im going to mess around and see what i can do! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Of course because it has a + on it, like I said if what you need is to ignore non alphanumeric characters you could have put that in your question, and it would be a different problem to solve. Basically need to use a regex to extract the alphanumeric characters. I fixed both your methods, though :)